# Periodically moving query results from Redshift to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have my data in a table in Redshift cluster. I want to periodically run a query against the Redshift table and store the results in a S3 bucket.

I will be running some data transformations on this data in the S3 bucket to feed into another system. As per AWS documentation I can use the `UNLOAD` command, but **is there a way to schedule this periodically**? I have searched a lot but I haven't found any relevant information around this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scheduling tool like [Airflow](http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/tutorial.html) to accomplish this task. Airflow seem-lessly connects to Redshift and S3. You can have a DAG action, which polls Redshift periodically and unloads the data from Redshift onto S3.

Comment: Is there a package in airflow for connecting with redshift and perform operations ? I couldn't find one

Comment: you can try experimenting with boto. I ve used it in the past to connect to S3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Redshift has the ability to schedule queries periodically. You would need to use another service for this. You could use a Lambda function, or you could schedule a cron job on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for AWS data pipeline service.

You can copy data from redshift to s3 using the RedshiftCopyActivity (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html).

I am copying the relevant content from the above URL for future purposes:

"*You can also copy from Amazon Redshift to Amazon S3 using RedshiftCopyActivity. For more information, see S3DataNode.
You can use SqlActivity to perform SQL queries on the data that you've loaded into Amazon Redshift.*"

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should try AWS Data Pipelines. You can schedule them to run periodically or on demand. I am confident that it would solve your use case